# update statement in C#,sql

Tags: c#, mysql

From the input I got from textbox1,textbox2 I want to check with DB and if the given user name and password combination is available, then I wanted to update the password with the input available in textbox3. Following is my code but it seems that my update statement is not working properly, please help me to correct it...

```
     protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost; database=e-learningsystem; uid=root; password=123;port=3307;");
        connection.Open();
        try
        {

            MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE lecturer Set Password= '" + TextBox3.Text + "' WHERE UserName='" + TextBox1.Text + "' AND Password='" + TextBox2.Text + "'", connection);
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
            {
                Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('Your Password Has Been Changed successfully!, Congratulations!')</script>");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('Your Password Has Not Been Changed successfully!, Sorry!')</script>");
            }
                connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert(ex.Message)</script>");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Eugh. "Sql injection", go google that, seriously. Your system is at risk. right now, I could use changing my password to destroy your database.

Comment: Then go read about plain text password storage. You shouldn't be storing passwords. You shouldn't even be encrypting them. You should apply a *salted hash* of the password (ideally with per-user salt) - and store the hash **only**.

Comment: Now: rant over - back to the original question: what do you mean by "not working properly"? What happens? Or doesn't?

Comment: Heh, since your code mentions "e-learningsystem", it makes Bobby Tables especially poignant: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: The updated value is not sent to DB

Comment: And also I just testing it thats why I didnt increase the security policy

Comment: the first thing to look at is what the final command you built was - I.e. what it looks like once concatenated. Does it work when you execute that code in isolation in your database tools? Also, are you sure it isn't throwing an exception? Your js in the exception block won't actually work (ex won't be defined) - so it could be that it is currently erroring then failing to tell you the error. Stepping through in the debugger looking at the inputs and the code path followed would be a good idea.

Comment: No it is not throwing any exception but not updating the table too....

Comment: does the execute return 1 or 0? Are you sure this isn't just the classic "I updated the copy of the db in bin/debug, but I'm looking a the different file in the project folder, then overwriting the change when I hit build" ?

Comment: Put in a string your query first like String sql =             "UPDATE lecturer Set Password= '" + TextBox3.Text + "' WHERE UserName='" + TextBox1.Text + "' AND Password='" + TextBox2.Text + "'" and from there debug the sql variable to see if younhave the right query.

Comment: I couldnt understand u... :(

Comment: What @Edper is saying is: find out what string you are building as the command. You could do the same thing in the debugger by printing `cmd1.CommandText`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to update password twice by calling `ExecuteNonQuery` twice. In first call to `ExecuteNonQuery` it would return `1` which is not collected and when second time when you call `ExecuteNonQuery` it would return `0`, so it will always execure the `else` part.

Make following changes -

```
    int updateCount = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (updateCount > 0)
    {
        Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('Your Password Has Been Changed successfully!, Congratulations!')</script>");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('Your Password Has Not Been Changed successfully!, Sorry!')</script>");
    }
```

Comment: No, only one 'ExecuteNonQuery' statement is there... why did you tel that there are too??? I couldnt understand it @Parag Meshram

Comment: @Jiya first one is `cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();` and second one is `if (cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)`. It would run update statement twice.

Comment: @Jiya it will execute your `UPDATE` statement twice. For testing the same, try replacing update with `INSERT` statement. It would insert two records.